# Copy same value till the new value is come in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have below data in my table

```
Name Break 
AA    1      
BB    1      
CC           
DD           
EE    1      
FF            
GG    1
```

Now I want below result.

Rule is like copy value of **Name** column in **Updated Name** column until we have found **1 in break** column.

```
Name Break UpdatedName
AA    1      AA
BB    1      BB
CC           BB
DD           BB
EE    1      EE 
FF           EE 
GG    1      GG
```

How can I get the above result?

Comment: Which column determines the order? Is it alphabetically from name?

Comment: Take a look at LAG for this type of thing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 What you need though is a reliable way to order your data. It is possible to use Name from your sample data but that is pretty brittle as a sorting column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "windowed" subquery.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Names') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Names

CREATE TABLE #Names (
    Name VARCHAR(2),
    Breaks INT)

INSERT INTO #Names (
    Name,
    Breaks)
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('C', NULL),
    ('D', NULL),
    ('E', 1),
    ('F', NULL),
    ('G', 1)

SELECT
    N.Name,
    N.Breaks,
    UpdatedName = (SELECT MAX(X.Name) FROM #Names AS X WHERE X.Name <= N.Name AND X.Breaks = 1)
FROM
    #Names AS N
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE(Name VARCHAr(10), [Break] INt)
INSERT INTO @Data

SELECT 'AA',1 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'BB',1 UNION ALL     
SELECT 'CC',NULL  UNION ALL     
SELECT 'DD',NULL  UNION ALL     
SELECT 'EE',1 UNION ALL     
SELECT 'FF',NULL  UNION ALL      
SELECT 'GG',1 

SELECT Name,[Break],
      IIF([Break]=1,Name,LAG(Name,1)OVER(ORDER BY  Name)) AS UpdatedName
 FROM @Data
```

Result/demo http://rextester.com/SGIB7287

Comment: Using a direct LAG won't drag previous records for more than 1 row.

Comment: This is not what I exactly want. But it is somewhat nearby my expectation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nested Select query like below
<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/BGK92185)**</kbd>

**Note:**  I have assumed that names are not necessarily in alphabetical order

```
; with cte as 
(select rn=row_number() over (order by (select NULL)), * from tbl)

select 
c1.Name, 
c1.[Break],
updateValue= 
 case 
   when c1.[break] is not null 
   then C1.Name 
   else
(
   select 
     TOP 1 
     c2.Name 
   from cte c2 
   where c2.rn<c1.rn 
   and c2.[break] is NOT NULL 
   order BY rn desc
) end
from cte c1  
    order by c1.rn
```